# ExoPlayer 2.8.2 Changes - TrackSelectionHelper and Selection Dialog

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have been away from development for a long time, today i found that ExoPlayer have removed some methods from it's library, such as TrackSelectionHelper. i searched about that in many places but i haven't found any helpful information.. anyway the Class no longer exists in the demo app, How can we switch between subtitles and stuff ?

Comment: try this
https://github.com/Sriharia/ExoPlayer-StatsForNerds

Comment: what does this library provides exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code from `TrackSelectionHelper` seems to have moved to `TrackSelectionView` as of ExoPlayer 2.9.1.

`TrackSelectionView` can be found in the `"com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui"` library extension.